# Box2D Contact Filter not triggering for bodies created on top of other bodies

Tags: box2d

I have a box2d setup for an Android game, using the port from LibGDX.

I'm using a Contact Filter to allow some bodies to pass through each other. However, when I create one such body at a location that another body occupies, so that they overlap, the two bodies get stuck, and the contact filter is never called. If I bump one object so that it loses contact and then comes back into contact with the other body, they pass through each other as expected. However, I would like to have the bodies pass through each other from the beginning.

I've noticed this behavior with one dynamic body and one dynamic, static or kinematic body.
My full setup is fairly complicated, so I don't know that my source would benefit anyone.

My main question is whether this sounds like normal box2d behavior (and if so if anyone knows a work around). On the other hand, if you have done something similar without getting this problem, I would like to know so that I can look for what bugs might be causing my program to run differently.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you using contact listener to filter contacts. Do you tried to use b2FixtureDef::filter field for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks Pavel! Yes, the b2FixtureDef filter worked. So is it fair to say that the fixture filter is intended for general categorical collision filtering, whereas the contact listener is intended for special conditional filtering, like a 1-way platform?

Comment: Yes, somehow like this. Maybe, I will post this as the answer to close the question?

Comment: Yes, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: Could you ever resolve this problem? For me the default filtering using the bitmasks and stuff isn't enough and I've spend the past 3 days trying to figure this out. I noticed it occurs only when I use `Body.setTransform` on a completely independent body...

Comment: I believe I used collision filtering, as the accepted answer below suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use [collision filtering](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering) via b2FixtureDef::filter field instead of contact listener.